# System which escapes infinitely often

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, control-theory, stability-in-odes, stability-theory

Is there a system of ordinary differential equations (over the reals) of the form

$$
\begin{align}
\dot{x}(t) &= f(x(t)) \\
x(0) &= x_0
\end{align}
$$

with the following properties:

- $f(0) = 0$
- $f$ is continuously differentiable everywhere
- $f$ does not have any singularities (implied by the second property)
- $x(t)$ has infinitly many singularities

For example, the system

$$
\begin{align}
\dot{x}(t) &= x(t)^2 \\
x(0) &= 1
\end{align}
$$

satisfies the first three properties but its solution is

$$
x(t) = \frac{1}{1 - t}
$$

so it has only one singularity at $t = 1$ and so it fails the fourth property.

Another example (taken from the comment of Lutz Lehmann) is the system

$$
\begin{align}
\dot{x}(t) &= x(t)^2 + 1 \\
x(0) &= 0
\end{align}
$$

which satisfies the last three properties as its solution

$$
x(t) = \tan(t)
$$

has infinitley many singularities, namely $\frac{\pi}{2}(2 k + 1)$ for $k \in \mathbb{Z}$. However, it fails the first property because $f(0) \neq 0$ (in fact the system has no equilibrium at all).

Is there a system with the above properties which has solutions with infinitely many singularities?

Comment: You mean that somehow the solution passing through $+\infty$ comes back from $-\infty$ and loops around infinitively often? So like $y'=1+y^2$ having the tangent function as solution? This can be made formally correct by setting, as typical for a Riccati equation, $y=-u'/u$ to get $u''+u=0$ which has a solution everywhere, so formally one could say that in the $y$ solution one has still the same solution after a singularity.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Yes, something like the $\tan$ function as solution but with $f(0) = 0$. Therefore $\dot{y}(t) = 1 + y(t)^2$ doesn't work for me unfortunatly because it doesn't satisfy the first property.

Comment: One could simply make the constant into an extra variable, $\dot y(t)=x(t)^2+y(t)^2$ and arrange that $x$ has both $1$ and $0$ as constant solutions, $\dot x(t)=x(t)(1-x(t))$.

Comment: @LutzLehmann This is a clever trick, thank you! If you post this as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: @LutzLehmann That's a brilliant idea!